# How to fetch names of virtual tables?

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, fts5

Example schema:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE posts USING FTS5(title, body);
```

Select table names:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

Result:

```
posts
posts_data
posts_idx
posts_content
posts_docsize
posts_config
```

How to fetch result only for virtual tables, without `*_data`, `*_idx`, `*_content`, `*_docsize` and `*_config`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FTS modules use [shadow tables](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#shadow_tables) to store the actual data and its indexes.

But those are 'real' tables, so you can simply use a filter to get only `sqlite_master` entries for virtual tables:

```
SELECT name
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type = 'table'
  AND sql LIKE 'CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE%';
```